# Specifying tag context when using acts_as_taggable_on and jQuery autocomplete

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, jquery-autocomplete, acts-as-taggable-on

I am using the gems https://github.com/mbleigh/acts-as-taggable-on and https://github.com/crowdint/rails3-jquery-autocomplete to implement tags on a Rails 4 app.

I have a model named `Question` with two distinct categories (contexts) of tags: `:topics` and `:courses`. The issue I cannot seem to solve is to filter the tags for autocomplete so that only the tags from the proper context are offered to the user. Otherwise the basic functionality of tags and autocomplete works fine, meaning that the user can type the first three letters of a given tag, and be offered a list of tags to select from (just not filtered by context).

**question.rb**

```
acts_as_taggable_on   :topics, :courses
```

**questions_controller.rb**

```
autocomplete :topic, :name, :class_name => 'ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag'
autocomplete :course, :name, :class_name => 'ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag'
```

Note: I tried to change the `:class_name` to `ActsAsTaggableOn::Course` or `ActsAsTaggableOn::Topic`, but got a (somewhat expected) error: `NameError (uninitialized constant ActsAsTaggableOn::Topic):`

**questions/_form.html.erb**

```
<%= f.autocomplete_field :course_list, autocomplete_course_name_questions_path, :"data-delimiter" => ', ' %>
<%= f.autocomplete_field :topic_list, autocomplete_topic_name_questions_path, :"data-delimiter" => ', ' %>
```

**config/routes.rb**

```
resources :questions do
  get :autocomplete_topic_name, :on => :collection
  get :autocomplete_course_name, :on => :collection
end
```

**Gemfile**

```
gem 'acts-as-taggable-on', '~> 3.4.1'
gem 'rails3-jquery-autocomplete', '~> 1.0.14'
```

Should I think of ditching `rails3-jquery-autocomplete` and use the jQuery UI widget directly? Is there perhaps a way of using the `:scopes` option from `rails3-jquery-autocomplete` to achieve the desired result? Am I just approaching the problem in the wrong way by using different tag contexts in the same model? Perhaps override the `autocomplete_...` methods in the `Questions` controller to filter the proper tags? Any and all thoughts are appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

In the hope that this helps someone else, here's how I solved this issue.

First and foremost, I replaced jQuery autocomplete with jQuery Tokeninput, found at: http://loopj.com/jquery-tokeninput/. I mostly followed the recipe found on this website: http://bloginius.com/blog/2013/12/31/how-integrate-acts-as-taggable-on-with-jquery-token-input-with-rails-3/. I suspect that my solution is not as efficient or elegant as the author's, but I had to adapt it to work with Rails 4 and using two "contexts" (`:topics` and `:courses`) instead of `:tags`.

Here's the code:

**assets/javascripts/questions.js.coffee**

```
jQuery ->
  $('#question_topic_list_tokens').tokenInput '/questions/topics.json',
    theme: 'facebook'
    minChars: 3
    allowCustomEntry: false
    preventDuplicates: true
    prePopulate: $('#question_topic_list_tokens').data('load')

jQuery ->
  $('#question_course_list_tokens').tokenInput '/questions/courses.json',
  theme: 'facebook'
  minChars: 3
  allowCustomEntry: false
  preventDuplicates: true
  prePopulate: $('#question_course_list_tokens').data('load')
```

**controllers/questions_controller.rb**

```
before_filter :find_topic_tags, only: [:new, :create, :edit, :update]
before_filter :find_course_tags, only: [:new, :create, :edit, :update]

def topics
  topics = Question.topic_counts.by_tag_name(params[:q]).map{|t| {id: t.name, name: t.name }}
  respond_to do |format|
    format.json { render json: topics }
  end
end

def courses
  courses = Question.course_counts.by_tag_name(params[:q]).map{|t| {id: t.name, name: t.name }}
  respond_to do |format|
    format.json { render json: courses }
  end
end

def question_params
  params.require(:question).permit(..., :topic_list_tokens, :course_list_tokens, ...)
end

def find_topic_tags
  @question_topics = params[:id].present? ? Question.find(params[:id]).topics.map{|t| {id: t.name, name: t.name }} : []
end

def find_course_tags
  @question_courses = params[:id].present? ? Question.find(params[:id]).courses.map{|t| {id: t.name, name: t.name }} : []
end
```

**qmodels/question.rb**

```
acts_as_taggable_on   :topics, :courses

attr_reader   :course_list_tokens, :topic_list_tokens

def topic_list_tokens=(tokens)
  self.topic_list = tokens.gsub("'", "")
end

def course_list_tokens=(tokens)
  self.course_list = tokens.gsub("'", "")
end
```

**views/questions/_form.html.erb**

```
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-3 control-label">
          <%= f.label :course_list_tokens, "course tags (separated by commas)" %><br/>
        </div>
        <div class="controls col-md-4">
          <%= f.text_field :course_list_tokens, data: {load: @question_courses} %>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 text-muted">(optional)</div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-3 control-label">
              <%= f.label :topic_list_tokens, "topic tags (separated by commas)" %><br/>
        </div>
        <div class="controls col-md-4">
          <%= f.text_field :topic_list_tokens, data: {load: @question_topics} %>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 text-muted">(optional)</div>
    </div>
```

**config/initializers/acts_as_taggable_on.rb**

```
ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag.send(:include, <YOUR APP>::TagExtend)
```

**config/routes.rb**

```
resources :questions do
  collection do
    get :topics, as: :topics
    get :courses, as: :courses
  end
end
```

**lib/tag_extend.rb**

```
module TagExtend
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    scope :by_tag_name, -> name { where("name like ?", "%#{name}%") }
  end
end
```